# How to solve "building the main Guest Additions module Failed"

Tags: centos, compiling, software-installation, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I tried to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions module in a VM guest running  CentOS but I get this error message when everything else was okay:

> building the main Guest Additions module Failed

Since I'm very new to CentOS and VirtualBox, I have no idea about to solve this and wasnt able to find any solution searching the internet (the only post I found didn't help me).

Here is the log:

> /usr/src/vboxguest-4.1.14/vboxguest/build_in_tmp: line 55: make :
>   command not found Creating user for the Guest additions. Creating udev
>   rule for the Guest additions kernel module

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You lack the `make` command. [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) is a utility that is often used to build programs from source; it runs the [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) on every source file in the right order. You need to install the `make` package, and possibly others: the [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) compiler, and the kernel headers (files generated during the compilation of the Linux kernel, that are necessary to compile third-party modules).

I hardly ever use CentOS, but I think the right command is:

```
yum install gcc make kernel-devel
```

or (will install more than you need)

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

You may need to [install](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=14408) other packages as well.

You need to run this command as root; depending on whether you use `su` or `sudo`:

```
su -c 'yum install …'
sudo yum install …
```

Comment: Restart was required after update in my case. Centos 6.8

Answer (score 4):

On a current **CentOS 7 minimal install** you need:

```
sudo yum install gcc kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 0):

All i did to fix this problem is followed the suggestion by guest additions installer:

The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following
module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
The missing package can be probably installed with

```
yum install kernel-uek-devel-2.6.39-400.215.10.el6uek.i686
```

After that i just retried to run guest additions installer and everything went perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS 7 I needed to do install DKMS via epel. Here is my complete list of commands.

```
sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install dkms -y
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
sudo yum install kernel-devel -y
sudo yum upgrade -y
```

**reboot the vm**

After reboot - I used vagrant vbguest (https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) to install Guest Additions.